# JavaScript function to hide buttons if specific text shows

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function called `hideButtons` that i want to hide buttons if certain text is present in the paragraph.
The paragraph goes through a list of names that the user either likes or dislikes and then when there are no more names then the buttons disappear.

Obviously this is sudo at the moment:

```
function hideButtons(){
      if namespace.indexOf("Out of people"){
        #likeButton = hidden;
        #dislikeButton = hidden;
      }
    }
```

This is a working function

```
function showName(){
      var name = names[0];
      if (!name){
        name = 'Out of people';
      }
      console.log(names)
      document.getElementById('namespace').innerHTML = name;
    }
```

And the html:

```
 <body>
    <p id='namespace'> Namelist </p>
    <button id="likebutton" type="button">Like</button>
    <button id="dislikebutton" type="button">Dislike</button>

  </body>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Where are you stuck?  Are you asking how to construct an `if` block?  How to find an element on the page?  How to check if a string contains a given substring?  How to modify the styling of an element?  Something else?

Comment: What do you mean by 'this is sudo at the moment'?

Comment: @HopefulLlama: I think he/she meant "pseudo"

Comment: when you ask questions on SO you should actually ask a question.

Comment: @PootieTang it's kinda obvious from the title but yeh fair enough

Answer (score 1):

You are sort of mixing up javascript and jQuery.

In javascript, to get the value of a `p` tag:

```
  var ns = document.getElementById('namespace').innerHTML;
```

the same thing in jQuery:

```
  var ns = $('#namespace').text();
```

jQuery uses the CSS selectors to identify elements, javascript does not.

Here is a semi-working version of your code.

```js
var lb = document.getElementById('likebutton');
lb.addEventListener('click', hideButtons, false);
var db = document.getElementById('dislikebutton');
db.addEventListener('click', hideButtons, false);

function hideButtons(){
  var ns = document.getElementById('namespace').innerHTML;
  alert(ns);
  if (ns.indexOf("Namelist") > -1 ){
    lb.style.display = 'none';
    db.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
function showName(){
  var name = names[0];
  if (!name){
    name = 'Out of people';
  }
  console.log(names)
  document.getElementById('namespace').innerHTML = name;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id='namespace'>Namelist</p>

  <button id="likebutton" type="button">Like</button>
  <button id="dislikebutton" type="button">Dislike</button>

</body>
```

---

Here is the same code in jQuery:

```js
$('#likebutton, #dislikebutton').click(function(){
    var ns = $('#namespace').text();
    if ( ns.indexOf('Namelist') > -1 ){
      $('#likebutton').hide();
      $('#dislikebutton').hide();
    }else{
      alert('P tag does not contain the word namespace');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <p id='namespace'>Namelist</p>

  <button id="likebutton" type="button">Like</button>
  <button id="dislikebutton" type="button">Dislike</button>

</body>
```

Comment: to get the text in a paragraph you use text(), not val(), that latter is stricktly for inputs.

Comment: also, i don't see how he is mixing jquery in there whatsoever, but js does in fact have methods to use css selectors, like `querySelector()`

Comment: Thanks for catching the `.val()` vs `.text()` typo - you'll note I had used the correct method in the "jQuery version" at bottom.

Comment: The thanks goes to you for catching it - also allowed me to discover the cool userscripts you've written and referenced on your profile. Well done and +1